# What it the best way to store passwords with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an entity, let's call it `User`, mapped to a table in my database and it has a property called `Password`:

```
public class User 
{
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to make sure that the password is always encrypted when the property is "set", and decrypted on "get".

In my case, I need a two-way encryption algorithm so I can't use a hash function. Assume I have a Cipher object that will do the encrypt / decrypt functions, I want a way that I can hide the plain text passwords from clients that use the class.

I could add additional methods that do the functions for me:

```
. . .
public string GetDecryptedPassword(ICipher cipher)  
{
    return cipher.DecryptString(password);
}

public void SetEncrtypedPassword(ICipher cipher, password) 
{
    password = cipher.EncryptedString(password);
}
. . .
```

Or just do the decrypt/encrypt outside the class:

```
var cipher = new Cipher();
var user = new User { password = cipher.EncryptedString(aPassword), Username = "bob" };
context.Users.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges();

. . .

var cipher = new Cipher();
var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username = "bob);
var password = cipher.DecryptString(user.password);
```

But then, in the latter case, I have to run around everywhere I touch the password and add the encrypt/decrypt code. Both solutions seems like an awkward kludge and really don't solve the problem of someone going behind the encrypt/decrypt methods to set/get the raw password and making a message of things.

Is there better way to do this? Is there an "accepted" way that this is normally done using Microsoft EF Core?

Thanks.

Comment: `I need a two-way encryption algorithm` Why? If you're storing it only for validation, you never need to decrypt.

Comment: Because password validation is not done by my application.  It is passed to another application that does the validation.  I only store it for backup/recovery purposes.

Comment: Then let the another program to handle those. For validation, just receive it and pass along as soon as possible, making your best effort to clear the used memory afterwards. As for recovery, this is often done in form of a password reset link or something similar, but in no case the original password is used. A forgotten password is just reseted, not handed over again. By storing it you're creating a serious **security vulnerability**. Just don't store it at all is the only sane approach to both problems. Delegate to the application that handles the password.

Comment: As much as I appreciate your answer, that won't work and the reasons for it are too lengthy to explain.  Trust me that I have looked at all aspects of this problem and know for certain that your suggested solution will not work in my case.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there an "accepted" way that this is normally done using Microsoft EF Core?

Yes.  The two patterns used in EF Core are

1. Use a Not-Mapped Property that reads and writes to a [Backing Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field?tabs=data-annotations)
2. Using a [Value Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations):

> Value converters allow property values to be converted when reading
> from or writing to the database. This conversion can be from one value
> to another of the same type (**for example, encrypting strings**) or from
> a value of one type to a value of another type (for example,
> converting enum values to and from strings in the database.)

Comment: Thanks David.  Backing field will definitely help but I don't know if Value Conversion will work for me since I have to inject an ICipher object, which needs to be built using a key stored in a database.   I was hoping I could do it with DI but I can't see how that would work with Value Conversion.

Comment: Yep. See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12205. Short of loading the key at startup and storing it in a static variable, there’s not a good way to get at it in a value conversion.